# php need working code as example of password hashing

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching the internet for what type of hashing algorithm should I use to store passwords in MySQL database and for sending email confirmation messages with hashed token, the algorithm should include:
 1- at least 14 chars random salt (uding udev random) 
2-a key that will be stored on the server 
3-timestamp 
4-a very strong and secure hashing algorithm using the function hash_***(is this the best?)

I haven't found elegent code that workds, could you please show me

Thank you

Comment: As stated in response to your previous question, you should be using PHP's [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function for generating passwords; and [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify them; the php docs provide examples showing how to use these functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the examples provided in [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) under [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing):

```
require 'password.php';

$passwordHash = password_hash('secret-password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (password_verify('bad-password', $passwordHash)) {
    // Correct Password
} else {
    // Wrong password
}
```

**DO NOT** under any circumstances "invent" your own algorithm. These are notoriously tricky to get right and unless you have a background in cryptography you will almost certainly get it dangerously wrong.

Comment: should I use it for email confirmation tokens also?

Comment: Confirmation tokens sent by private email are not generally an attack vector, especially if they're time limited and only work once. To generate those the best plan is a completely random string of 12-20 characters. You could password encrypt them if you want, that wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: could you also please explain how I store salt and use it ?

Comment: The `password_hash` method creates a singular string that incorporates three elements: The salt, the hashed password, and the method used to generate it. This makes it a lot easier to use than other methods that require two or more columns to capture the data. As always, read the [documentation on `password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for more details.